# java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name com.elsevier.agreement.AgreementResourceBundle, locale en_US

Tags: java

```
java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name com.elsevier.agreement.AgreementResourceBundle, locale en_US
        at java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(ResourceBundle.java:836)
        at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:805)
        at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:576)
        at org.apache.taglibs.i18n.BundleTag.findBundle(BundleTag.java:240)
        at org.apache.taglibs.i18n.BundleTag.doStartTag(BundleTag.java:321)
        at org.apache.jsp.jsp.agreement_005fSuccess_005femail_jsp._jspx_meth_i18n_005fbundle_005f0(agreement_005fSuccess_005femail_js
        at org.apache.jsp.jsp.agreement_005fSuccess_005femail_jsp._jspx_meth_dsp_005fpage_005f0(agreement_005fSuccess_005femail_jsp.j
        at org.apache.jsp.jsp.agreement_005fSuccess_005femail_jsp._jspService(agreement_005fSuccess_005femail_jsp.java:88)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:387)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:320)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:266)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.TailPipelineServlet.service(TailPipelineServlet.java:90)
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:116)
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.DispatcherPipelineServletImpl.service(DispatcherPipelineServletImpl.java:202)
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:116)
        at atg.servlet.http.CookieBufferServlet.service(CookieBufferServlet.java:97)
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:116)
        at atg.userprofiling.ExpiredPasswordServlet.service(ExpiredPasswordServlet.java:356)
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:116)
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.MimeTyperPipelineServlet.service(MimeTyperPipelineServlet.java:206)
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:116)
        at atg.droplet.DropletEventServlet.service(DropletEventServlet.java:565)
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:116)
        at atg.servlet.sessionsaver.SessionSaverServlet.service(SessionSaverServlet.java:2442)
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:116)
        at atg.commerce.order.CommerceCommandServlet.service(CommerceCommandServlet.java:128)
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:116)
        at atg.commerce.promotion.PromotionServlet.service(PromotionServlet.java:191)
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:116)
        at atg.userprofiling.AccessControlServlet.service(AccessControlServlet.java:602)
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:116)
        at atg.userprofiling.PageEventTriggerPipelineServlet.service(PageEventTriggerPipelineServlet.java:169)
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:116)
        at atg.userprofiling.SessionEventTrigger.service(SessionEventTrigger.java:461)
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:116)
        at atg.userprofiling.ProfileRequestServlet.service(ProfileRequestServlet.java:480)
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:116)
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.DynamoPipelineServlet.service(DynamoPipelineServlet.java:469)
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:116)
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.PathAuthenticationPipelineServlet.service(PathAuthenticationPipelineServlet.java:370)
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:116)
        at atg.userprofiling.sso.PassportServlet.service(PassportServlet.java:561)
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:116)
        at atg.servlet.security.ThreadUserBinderServlet.service(ThreadUserBinderServlet.java:91)
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:116)
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.HeadPipelineServlet.passRequest(HeadPipelineServlet.java:1100)
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.HeadPipelineServlet.service(HeadPipelineServlet.java:782)
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.service(PipelineableServletImpl.java:231)
        at atg.filter.dspjsp.PageFilter.doFilter(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:173)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:182)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:84)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:104)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:157)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:241)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)
```

Comment: I'm gonna take a shot in the dark here - your problem might be a missing resource, possibly a bundle.

Answer (score 2):

The exception is telling you that it cannot find a resource bundle containing (presumably) locale-specific message strings for some application.  There are many possible reasons for this, but the most likely reasons are that your deployed webapp is missing a JAR file or that you've put it in the wrong place in the webapp.

Comment: ya ur right...jar file was missed